# Error installing CentOS 8 (8.2-2004) Missing packages/programs in ISO

Tags: centos, system-installation, ethernet

I am enthusiastic about trying new things. I have previously used `CentOS 7` (VirtualBox) and `CentOS 6` on physical machine.
Now, I want to use `CentOS 8` on physical machine again.

I get image from [CentOS 8.2-2004](http://mirror.datto.com/CentOS/8.2.2004/isos/x86_64/CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-dvd1.iso)

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_a_standard_rhel_installation/preparing-for-your-installation_installing-rhel#making-media_preparing-for-your-installation

For partitions I follow:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-disk-partitioning-setup-x86#sect-recommended-partitioning-scheme-x86

Instead of:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_a_standard_rhel_installation/graphical-installation_graphical-installation#manual-partitioning_graphical-installation

I have for Memory: `16.0GB DDR4-2666 DDR4 SODIMM 2666MHz`

**Here the partition scheme.**

[image]

I'm using a `Lenovo ThinkBook 13S (20RR)`, it does not have network Ethernet else `Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz`.

CentOS 8 is not recognizing my WLAN interface, for this reason When I am in the installation process, it gets blocked and does not progress.

Blocked **Installing tar.x86_64 (227/1579) for two hours**
[image]

I solved, using a external USB Ethernet, AX88772A.

1. **`Is it not possible to install CentOS Without Ethernet port available?`**

Now, I was selecting my desired packages/programs

[image]

**But, I get an ERROR.** Maybe I can fix it removing Developing packages/programs.
[image]

I checked my USB. **Maybe it is a Bug**

2. **`What alternative I have in order to solve this error?`**

EDIT 2:

Now, I was trying only **Workstation** *Base Environment*, without *Aditional Software*.
[image]
Blocked **Installing tracker.x86_64 (1139/1392) again**

**Checking SHA-256** It's fine!
[image]

**EDIT 3**

SOURCE
[image]

Checking
[image]

Warning
[image]

**Limited** Maybe some wrong in the package!
[image]

Comment: Is it a netinstall image? You should try the full DVD, so that no internet connection will be needed.

Comment: @Krackout I'm using 7.7G full ISO DVD1.

Comment: If you still have the iso used for making the boot usb, check the hash. Could be something with your download. If the hash is correct, next step I'd try would be to make a VM using the same .iso. If VM installation succeeds, the problem might have occured in usb tranfering of iso.

Comment: @Krackout Hmm, Appears the iso originally is bad (the checking SHA-256 is good), testing the ISO with VirtualBox the options are reduced, like images in real physical machine. Then some packages are not included in the iso (although it shows the menu, it doesn't really bring the packages)